# Match star but not dot star

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex pattern that will succeed for string `s*` but not for string `.*`. I'm finding this tricky. I expected `[^.]\\*` or `[^\\.]\\*` or `(?<!\\.)\\*` to work but none of these does it.

Any ideas?

```
@Test
public void testTemp() {
    String regex = "[^.][*]";
    if ("s*".matches(regex)) {
        if (".*".matches(regex)) {
            System.out.println("Success");
        } else {
            // This exception gets thrown.
            throw new RuntimeException("Wrongly matches dot star");
        }
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Does not match star");
    }
}
```

And please don't tell me that my use case is stupid. I have a perfectly legitimate use case that is a bit difficult to articulate clearly. Suffice to say, I'm not confused.

Comment: It would be best to always describe your actual use-case, to avoid the trap of the [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Good point. It's difficult, but basically I have a huge regex in a file that I'm trying to match the JSON response of coming back from some server. I need ".*" to ignore certain parts that are non-deterministic. But `*` may well appear in the server response.

Comment: Please specify what kind of samples should it match and what shouldn't. If you just need it to match "s*", simply use an "s\\*" regexp :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern was correct, just that your second `if` statement was wrong try this

```
@Test
public void testTemp() {
    String regex = "[^.][*]";
    if ("s*".matches(regex)) {
        if (!".*".matches(regex)) {
            System.out.println("Success");
        } else {
            // This exception gets thrown.
            throw new RuntimeException("Wrongly matches dot star");
        }
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Does not match star");
    }
}
```

Comment: A pleasure answering.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that it matches the non-dot character as well. You should use [*negative lookbehind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead:

```
(?<![.])[*]
```

[Regex101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/hH3dY7/1)

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<![.])[*]");
if (regex.matcher("s*").find()) {
    if (!regex.matcher(".*").find()) {
        System.out.println("Success");
    } else {
        // This exception gets thrown.
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrongly matches dot star");
    }
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Does not match star");
}
```

[Java demo.](http://ideone.com/ePgarf)

Comment: I tried this but strangely it doesn't work. I was expecting it to.

Comment: Still, I get `"Doesn't match what I want to match"`

Comment: Your regex was fine. Just keep it.

Comment: @das This regex cannot work when using `matches()`, since it only matches 1 character `*`, the look-behind cannot ever be true. It works fine with `find()`, which is what the demo is using.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat [Here is a Java demo that uses this expression](http://ideone.com/ePgarf).

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat `[^.]\\*` doesn't work when the asterisk is the first or the only character in the string.

Answer (score 2):

You meant `if (! ".*".matches(regex)) {`